# Converting Code to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am having problem in this code while converting *vb6 code to vb.net*

Code:

```
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset
recset.Open("select * from mktrate", cnMain, 3, 3)
```

Error:

> "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another."

Answer (score 0):

cnMain is not defined. That is your connection.

Also 3 is a static cursor, 3 is also optimistic locking, does your database still support this (it probably does).